# Possibly a conflict with file names of .Net and Silverlight assemblies (TFS Deploy)

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, tfs

Following problem: we're using gated build with TFS 2012. As soon as the TFS starts the build, everything is just copied into one folder.

- Our actual application is a Silverlight application.
- Our unit tests though are put in .Net projects

One part of our application uses 3rd party controls. It uses a Silverlight assembly, which grants a certain functionality. The same functionality is given in a .Net assembly, which we use in a parallel project for server-side stuff and unit testing. It actually grants the same functionality (except the UI things). Both of those assemblies are referenced with "copy local = true".

If I build the solution **locally** (which contains both assemblies referenced in different projects), everything works fine. But as soon as I try to deploy it via TFS, the build fails because of a **FileIOException** or something. It tells me that the 3rd party assembly is not the proper file.

I think that occured, because when the TFS starts building, **everything** gets copied into one folder. **Both**: the .Net assembly and the Silverlight assembly. They both have the **same** file name. I think that's, what messes up the TFS build.

Do you have any suggestions for this problem? It's a requirement that we still have the "uber solution", which contains all the projects. So splitting up .Net and Silverlight projects isn't a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably due to when you are building through TFS or some Non-IDE builder you are somewhere having an output directory specified so its just collating all assemblies in one place, causing an issue.

You can either append a suffix to your silverlight project assemblies, which will just make the assembly output as "YourAssembly.silverlight.dll" rather than "YourAssembly.dll", it would not mess with namespaces internally, although this can be confusing to other people unfamiliar with your system, generally you would just use namespaces to split them out so your silverlight framework would be within a *.silverlight namespace which paired with your project name indicating the namespace difference would solve your problem.

Comment: Well that would be a solution. But those assemlies aren't actually developed by us. That's 3rd party assemblies. And that's not just one, it's about 50 of them. I think I can't simply rename them, can I?

And was it also possible to easily update those? Or would I need to rename the latest assemblies (published by the 3rd party company) and put them renamed onto the TFS?

Comment: It was implied that you owned these assemblies (i.e you have the project within your solution). So if these assemblies are ones you do not own then either rename them to stop the filename conflict (as its just a reference you can call them "SpacePotato.dll" and they would work fine). I would just rename the ones you reference (as those are all that will be built) and give them some sort of suffix indicating which is which, if that is not an option split the projects using them into a separate solution (although you said that wasnt an option)